# C#: Generate 100 random numbers between 1-1000 and output the max value

Tags: c#, random, generator

I'm very new to coding and I just can't wrap my head around Loops/Arrays/Randoms. I understand the concept but when it comes to applying it, I'm just lost.

Here I'm trying to generate 100 random numbers between 1-1000 and it has to output the maximum value. Here's my code so far:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int nums = rnd.Next(0, 1001);
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{

}
Console.WriteLine(nums);
Console.ReadLine();
```

It's only giving me one number. :(
I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: Once you get past loops then try doing it this way: `Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => rnd.Next(0, 1001)).Max();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accumulate your random generated number to the array and then by using `Max` function of the array you can find the maximum value

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] intArr = new int[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < intArr.Length; i++)
        {
            int num = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
            intArr[i] = num;
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        int maxNum = intArr.Max();
        Console.WriteLine("The max num is:" + maxNum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[## Click to watch online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C3RcaT)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call rnd.Next() inside loop.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    int nums = rnd.Next(0, 1001);
    Console.WriteLine(nums);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, are you asking like this?

```
Random random = new Random();

int[] nums = new int[100];

// when for loop ends, nums are full of 100 numbers
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    int newNum = random.Next(1, 1000);

    // show every number
    Console.WriteLine(newNum);

    nums[i] = newNum;
}

// get the max number
var maxNum = nums.Max();

Console.WriteLine(maxNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be initializing a variable that stores your max. Then generate a random number within your iterative block and if it is greater than your max, set it as the new max.

```
Random r = new Random();
int max = 0; //declare our max variable
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int rand = r.Next(0, 1001);
    if(rand > max) //if the new random value is greater than our max, set max = rand
        max = rand;
}

Console.WriteLine(max); //Output the maximum value
Console.ReadLine();
```

If you want to output every random value and then output the max out of all the values generated, simply modify the code above by outputting `rand` within your loop as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the code for Loops/Arrays/Randoms all working together you can use the below with the comments walking through what each line is doing ([Working .NET Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/21gz8J))

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Pass in what range we want our randomly generated numbers to be in
    // In your case, between 1 - 1000 and we want to create 100 of them.
    //(See GenerateRandomNumbers())

    var random = GenerateRandomNumbers(1, 1000, 100);

    //Take our newly returned randomly created numbers and 
    //pass them to our GetMaxNumber method so it can find the Max number
    //See (GetMaxNumber())

    var result = GetMaxNumber(random);

    //We now have our max number; print it to the Console.

    Console.WriteLine("Max: " + result);
}

public static int GetMaxNumber(params int[] inputs)
{
    //Create a variable that will store the largest number we find in our array

    int max = inputs[0];

    //Iterate (loop) through all of the 100 values in our array that we passed in
    //Here we define "input" which will hold the value for each value in inputs as we check
    //if the value of input is greater than our current value of max. If it is greater than our
    //current value of max, then we need to update max to now be equal to the value of our input.
    //Note: it will do this comparison 100 times beginning with the first value in the inputs array

    foreach (var input in inputs)
    {
        if (input > max)
        {
            //input's value is greater than the current value of max; update max so that it is equal to the current value of input.

            max = input;
        }
        //no more code; return to top of foreach loop and set input to the next value in inputs
    }

    //When we get here, it means our foreach loop has completed going through and comparing all 100 values of inputs to see which value is the largest.
    //now return this value to Main()

    return max;
}

public static int[] GenerateRandomNumbers(int beginRange, int endRange, int maxNumbers)
{
    // Instantiate random number generator

    Random rnd = new Random();

    //Generate and display 

    int[] intArr = new int[maxNumbers];

    //Generate 100 numbers with numbers between 1 and 1000

    for (int i = 0; i < intArr.Length; i++)
    {
        int num = rnd.Next(beginRange, endRange);
        intArr[i] = num;
    }

    return intArr;
}
```